# How to handle data skew in Spark window functions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a data set that I'm trying to process in PySpark. The data (on disk as Parquet) contains user IDs, session IDs, and metadata related to each session. I'm adding a number of columns to my dataframe that are the result of aggregating over a window. The issue I'm running into is that all but 4-6 executors will complete quickly and the rest run forever without completing. My code looks like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

empty_col_a_cond = ((f.col("col_A").isNull()) |
                         (f.col("col_A") == ""))

session_window = Window.partitionBy("user_id", "session_id") \
                       .orderBy(f.col("step_id").asc())

output_df = (
    input_df 
    .withColumn("col_A_val", f
                .when(empty_col_a_cond, f.lit("NA"))
                .otherwise(f.col("col_A"))) 
    # ... 10 more added columns replacing nulls/empty strings
    .repartition("user_id", "session_id")
    .withColumn("s_user_id", f.first("user_id", True).over(session_window)) 
    .withColumn("s_col_B", f.collect_list("col_B").over(session_window)) 
    .withColumn("s_col_C", f.min("col_C").over(session_window)) 
    .withColumn("s_col_D", f.max("col_D").over(session_window)) 
    # ... 16 more added columns aggregating over session_window
    .where(f.col("session_flag") == 1) 
    .where(f.array_contains(f.col("s_col_B"), "some_val"))
)
```

In my logs, I see this over and over:

```
INFO ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray: Reached spill threshold of 4096 rows, switching to org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter
INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 92 spilling sort data of 9.2 GB to disk (2  times so far)
INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 91 spilling sort data of 19.3 GB to disk (0  time so far)
```

Which suggests that Spark can't hold all the windowed data in memory. I tried increasing the internal settings `spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold` and `spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.spill.threshold`, which helped a little but there are still executors not completing.

I believe this is all caused by some skew in the data. Grouping by both `user_id` and `session_id`, there are 5 entries with a count >= 10,000, 100 records with a count between 1,000 and 10,000, and 150,000 entries with a count less than 1,000 (usually count = 1).

```py
input_df \
    .groupBy(f.col("user_id"), f.col("session_id")) \
    .count() \
    .filter("count < 1000") \
    .count()

# >= 10k, 6
# < 10k and >= 1k, 108
# < 1k, 150k
```

This is the resulting job DAG:

[image: Spark job DAG]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Not yet. I tried salting the data, repartitioning it, but no luck yet.